# I am trying to implement a falling animation to my game and i am having alot of problems doing so

Tags: c#, unity

i am trying to have it so that when my character isnt touching anything he plays an animation of falling, yet when he moves from one game object to different one, he plays the animation. for example if he steps from one platform to another, even if he doesnt have to jump, he plays the falling animation. How would i make it so that when he jumps and doesnt touch anything he plays the animation?

```
  void Update() 
{
    if(!colliding)
    {
        animator.Play ("Fall");
    }
  }
  void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collision)
{
    colliding = true;

}
void OnCollisionExit(Collision collision)
{
    colliding = false;
}
```

Comment: You could keep track of the character's movement in the direction towards the ground. You can then use either distance fallen or velocity (towards the ground) to trigger the animation.

Comment: You could make variables for vertical speed, and use the falling animation when they are a certain amount.

Answer (score 1):

This can be done with a short timer. It is probably not a problem if the animation doesn't start immediately when the character starts falling.

```
public float delay = 0.1f; // Animation starts after 0.1 seconds of falling
private float lastCollision = 0.0f;
void Update() 
{
    if(Time.timeSinceLevelLoad > lastCollision + delay)
    {
        animator.Play ("Fall");
    }
}


void OnCollisionStay(Collision collision)
{
    lastCollision = Time.timeSinceLevelLoad;
}
```